# navbar con alto fijo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Saludos tengo un navbar de **Bootstrap 3.3.6** el mismo al cargar la pagina se muestra fijo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando se despliega hacia abajo el navbar toma otro alto algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que uso es:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: white;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
             <div class="navbar-header page-scroll" style="margin-left: -50px;margin-top: -30px;margin-bottom: -15px;">
                <a class="navbar-header page-scroll" href="#page-top" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                    <img src="logo2019.png" alt="" width="290px;" height="170px">
                </a>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#portfolio">Portafolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#services">Aplicativos</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#about">Acerca de</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#clientes">Clientes</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#contact">Contacto</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#imagenes">Galería</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#video">Video</a>
                </li>
                 <li >
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#notices">Noticias</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

no uso estilos adicionales tan solo el standart de Bootstrap, gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Parece que el problema esta en el tamaño del logo, intente reducir al altura (height) para que este igual a la del NavBar.

Comment: Hola Diego, no entiendo muy bien cuál es el problema o que tienes o lo que deseas lograr, ¿podrías añadir más detalles a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

intenta quitarle las clases de page-scroll y los margin, debería funcionar.

`<div class="navbar-header page-scroll" style="margin-left: -50px;margin-top: -30px;margin-bottom: -15px;">
<a class="navbar-header page-scroll" href="#page-top" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">`

Comment: Puedes quitar el div completo, si no me equivoco... lo de adentro no obviamente si no te quita el logo